# Trigonometric presentation of a complex number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need to present the following number 
$$
1-\sin\beta +  i \cos \beta,
$$
in a trigonometric fashion.

I know that I have to use $z=rcis(\theta)$. But it doesn't get me anywhere, i.e.,
$$
r = \sqrt{(1-\sin\beta)^2 + \cos^2 \beta } = \sqrt{2(1-\sin\beta}),
$$
where $\cos\beta =  \sqrt{(1-\sin\beta)/2}$...  Is there a way to solve it without getting in a much more messy identities that unfortunately don't help me much?

Thank you

Comment: _Hint_: $-\sin\beta+i\cos\beta=\sin-\beta+i\cos-\beta$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sine and cosine were interchanged, we could invoke the identities
$$1 - \cos\theta = 2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2} \qquad\text{and}\qquad \sin\theta = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cos\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Luckily, it's easy to swap sine and cosine: Define $\alpha := \frac{\pi}{2} - \beta$. Then the number in question becomes
$$1 - \cos\alpha + i \sin\alpha = 2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\left(\;\sin\frac{\alpha}{2} + i\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}\;\right)$$
Hmmm ... Again, it'd be convenient to swap sine and cosine. Using the same trick as before, we have

> $$2\; \cos\gamma \; \operatorname{cis} \gamma\qquad\text{where}\qquad\gamma = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\alpha}{2} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\beta}{2}$$

Note that 
$$2\cos\gamma = 2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2} = 2\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{2}} = \sqrt{2(1-\cos\alpha)} = \sqrt{2(1-\sin\beta)}$$
so you can write the above as

> $$\sqrt{2(1-\sin\beta)}\;\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{\beta}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

When $\text{z}\in\mathbb{C}$:
$$\text{z}=\Re\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im\left[\text{z}\right]i=\left|\text{z}\right|e^{\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i}=\left|\text{z}\right|\cos\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)+\left|\text{z}\right|\sin\left(\arg\left(\text{z}\right)+2\pi\text{k}\right)i$$
Where $\left|\text{z}\right|=\sqrt{\Re^2\left[\text{z}\right]+\Im^2\left[\text{z}\right]}$,$\arg\left(\text{z}\right)$ is the complex argument of $\text{z}$ and $\text{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

So, for:

$$\text{s}=1-\sin\left(\beta\right)+\cos\left(\beta\right)i$$

We get:

$$\left|\text{s}\right|=\sqrt{\left(1-\sin\left(\beta\right)\right)^2+\cos^2\left(\beta\right)}=\sqrt{2\left(1-\sin\left(\beta\right)\right)}$$

And:

1. When $\Re\left[\text{s}\right]>0$ and $\Im\left[\text{s}\right]>0$:
   $$\arg\left(\text{s}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\Im\left[\text{s}\right]}{\Re\left[\text{s}\right]}\right)=\arctan\left(\frac{\cos\left(\beta\right)}{1-\sin\left(\beta\right)}\right)=\text{arccot}\left(\sec\left(\beta\right)-\tan\left(\beta\right)\right)$$
2. When $\Re\left[\text{s}\right]<0$ and $\Im\left[\text{s}\right]>0$:
   $$\arg\left(\text{s}\right)=\pi-\arctan\left(-\frac{\Im\left[\text{s}\right]}{\Re\left[\text{s}\right]}\right)=\pi+\text{arccot}\left(\sec\left(\beta\right)-\tan\left(\beta\right)\right)$$

And so on. (I used radians)

Answer (score 1):

$$z=\underbrace{1-\sin\beta}_{r\cos\theta}+i\underbrace{\cos\beta}_{r\sin\theta}\\
\begin{cases}r\cos\theta=1-\sin\beta\\
r\sin\theta=\cos\beta\end{cases}\bigg\rbrace\Rightarrow \tan\theta=\frac{\cos\beta}{1-\sin\beta}, r=\sqrt{2-2\sin\beta}\\
z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) 
$$
where $r=\sqrt{2-2\sin\beta}, \theta=\arctan{\left(\frac{\cos\beta}{1-\sin\beta}\right)}$
To go further, use the half-angle formulas $\tan\frac{\beta}2=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ giving
$$\tan\theta=\frac{\cos\beta}{1-\sin\beta}=\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}=\frac 1t=\frac 1{\tan\frac{\beta}{2}}=\tan\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\beta2\right)\\
\theta=\frac\pi4-\frac\beta2\\
z=r\;\text{cis }\theta=\sqrt{2(1-\sin\beta)}\;\text{cis } \left(\frac\pi4-\frac\beta2\right)\\
$$

Comment: I see. Thank you. I forgot to mention that the answer in the notes that I have says that $z=\sqrt{2(1-\sin \beta}(cis(\pi/4 + \beta/2)$, $\beta \in (0, \pi/2)$. Does it make any sens? Are these answer identical? Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, if you want to express the answer in half-angle terms. See new edits. See also lab's answer below which give some helpful hints.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$1-\sin\beta=1-\cos\left(\dfrac\pi2-\beta\right)=2\sin^2\left(\dfrac{\pi-2\beta}4\right)$$

$$\cos\beta=\sin\left(\dfrac\pi2-\beta\right)=2\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi-2\beta}4\right)\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi-2\beta}4\right)$$

Now use the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) of atan$2$